# What's the alternative for using multiple generic type parameters in object-oriented design?

Tags: c#, generics

I am automating a collection of widgets written in Javascript. However, I am using C# and .NET for the automation.

These widgets have several ways of configuring them, so they can be used in multiple ways. Each of these ways that they can be used in, we call as templates. There are now three stages where they can be configured : Either in the base widget directory, or at the template level, or at the UI level where they will be consumed.

Now, the issue I have is, because Javascript is dynamically typed, the type of the template for some widgets gets identified at run time at the UI level. Until then, I have no way of knowing what template form the widget is going to take. And there are widgets, that contain other such configurable widgets within them.

The way, I am currently handling this in C# is, by adding Interface and implementation for each template of the widget. However, when I have to instantiate a widget, I need to specify what template type I would be using. So, I am forced to using multiple generic type parameters, since a single widget's properties can include other configurable widgets with different types.

I don't think this is the best way to do it, so I have been trying to look for any design patterns that might save me from doing it this disastrous way. 
Here's an example of a widget template Interface and its class in C# :

```
public interface IWidget1Template1<T,U>
{
    IWidget2<T> Heading { get; }

    IWidget3<U> Paragraph { get; }
}


 public class Widget1Template1<T,U> : Widget1 , IWidget1Template1<T,U>
 {

  public Widget1Template1(Resources)
  {}

  public IWidget2<T> Heading
  {
      if(typeof(T) == typeof(w2t1))
      {
        return (IWidget2<T>) new w2t1();
      }
      else
        return (IWidget2<T>)new w2t2();
  }

  public IWidget3<U> Paragraph
  {
      if(typeof(U) == typeof(w3t2))
      {
        return (IWidget3<U>) new w3t2();
      }
      else
        return (IWidget3<U>)new w3t1();
  }
```

The subsequent UI call will specify what template types would be used, while creating an object of the class Widget1Template1 like,

```
   public Widget1Template1 MidSection
   {
       return new Widget1Template1<w2t1, w3t1>(Resources);
   }
```

Comment: Well, so the code above doesn't compile (`typeof<>` isn't a thing). But more generally, I don't think trying to map javascript (JSON) to generic types is going to end well for you. Maybe this:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c) ?

Comment: .net has a dynamic type, so you can ducktype. Remember though you get no compile time support, so you need to get serious about unit tests.

Comment: Do you need to know the exact type at compile-time for everything? Why not just implement `IWidget` and put all the required code in there instead of typing everything to the specific widgets? What I mean is, do you need to know the actual widget type/interface for the heading and paragraph, instead of just a `IHeaderWidget` or `IParagraphWidget`?

Comment: @sircodesalot sorry, I meant typeof(), my mistake. I corrected it now.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes I do. Because the templates vary a lot among themselves. One template of the same widget, can have a link, the other might have an image. I would have preferred to make a simple IHeaderWidget or IParagraphWidget, but unfortunately I can't.

Comment: Can you please list some methods/properties of IWidget1/2/3 interfaces?

Comment: @sircodesalot We are not parsing the JSON objects, we have a very complex way of adding the widgets and their templates. So, currently, its all a manual process of figuring out the templates and adding them by hand, in C#.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are doing, but you can eliminate those `if/else` statements by using `return (IWidget3<U>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(U))`

Comment: @Gosha IWidget2, IWidget3 would be base classes of widgets, whose derived classes would be similar to IWidget1Template1.

Comment: @Brandon I didn't know about that syntax. Thanks, I can use that instead of the if/else it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Since all your interfaces have similar signature i propose you to keep only one interface IWidget and treat everything else as data, e.g. WidgetType and TemplateType could be strings, enums or classes but not Clr Types.

some code just to illustrate the idea:

```
interface IPage
{
    string Name { get; }
    IReadOnlyList<IWidget> Sections { get; }
}

interface IWidget 
{
    string Name { get; }
    ITemplate Template { get; set; }
    IReadOnlyList<IWidget> Widgets { get; }
}

interface ITemplate
{
    string Name { get; }
    IReadOnlyList<IElement> Elements { get; }
}

interface IElement
{
    string Name { get; }
    IList<Assestion> Assetions { get; }
}

class Assestion
{
    public AssetionSubject Subject { get; set; }
    public AssetionPredicate Predicate { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

enum AssetionSubject { InnerText, OuterHtml, etc }
enum AssetionPredicate { eq, neq, gt, lt, etc }
```

and the test code:

```
void AddTest(IPage page) 
{
    var listElement = page.Sections.First(s => s.Name == "ResultsSection")
        .Widgets.First(w => w.Template.Name == "BannerTemplate")
        .Template.Elements.First(e => e.Name == "List");

    listElement.Assetions.Add(new Assestion
    {
        Subject = AssetionSubject.InnerText,
        Predicate = AssetionPredicate.eq,
        Value = "Some banner"
    });
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite get that, could you elaborate please?
Currently, I do have an interface IWIdget for each Widget, which almost always contains only the constructors, as the templates are beginning to vary amongst themselves a lot not holding any common ground, and justifying themselves to be their own widgets. 
Anyway, so I think I can change it the way you are suggesting without affecting a lot, but I didn't still understand what do you mean by 'treat everything else as data'?

Comment: Interface describes contract - what methods you can invoke on instance. You've modeled metadata e.g. what template is used as interface but you don't actually have to. Model it as an object instance for example string templatetype="template1"

Comment: Yes, the Model is like that so that the Testers can invoke the methods on a specific template while looking at it, in the UI. I don't think modelling it as an object instance will serve the purpose.

Comment: Testes will not see CLR types, right? They will see type name,command name and parameters list and may be properties. You can code this. The implementation and the ui should not necessarily  have same logical structure.

Comment: Yes, Testers won't directly see the CLR types, they will only be dealing with them. However, since the automation is built around Page Objects, the implementation has to map the UI logically for the ease of the testers.
Let me give an instance of a simple Tester assertion statement :
ResultsPage.ResultsSection.BannerTemplate.List[0].InnerText.equals("Some banner");
If you can code something to this effect using your approach, I am all ears. Please provide some sample code so that I can follow properly.

Comment: Btw did you explored the CodedUI or Selenium automation frameworks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70059/discussion-between-gosha-and-setafire).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's way off from how I need this to be done. A lot of people have a dependency on the ease of usage of the code, so I can't really use this approach.
But thanks anyway for the effort, appreciate it.